# Getting the Average,Min, and Max of numbers in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with getting the min,max, and average of an elements of 2D array.

I have a 2D array which contains Students and Grades.

I am generating the grades with rand. For example When I enter 2,2 it prints me out

```
Courses : 01   02   Average   Min   Max
    ID   
    01     8   50     29
    02    74   59     29
```

, My average function takes the first ones average and doesnt take the others average.

Here is my code ;

```
int A[30][30];

int findAverage(int noOfStudents ,int noOfGrades ){

    float sum,average;




    for (int i = 0 ; i < noOfGrades ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<noOfStudents; j++) {

        sum += A[i][j];

        }
        average = sum / noOfGrades;
       // cout << "   " << format(average);
        sum = 0;
        return format(average);

    }
```

and here how I use it

```
int main() {

    int noOfCourses , noOfStudents;
    cin >> noOfCourses >> noOfStudents;
    cout << "Courses : " ;

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfCourses; i++) {
        if (i+1 >= 10) {

            cout << i+1 << "   ";
        }else{
            cout <<"0" << i+1 << "   ";

        }
    }

    cout << "Average   Min   Max";

    for(int i=0; i<noOfStudents; i++) {         //This loops on the rows.        

        for(int j=0; j<noOfCourses; j++) {     //This loops on the columns
            A[i][j] = genGrade(); 
        }
    }

    cout << "\n    ID   " << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<noOfStudents; i++) {  //This loops on the rows.

        if (i+1 >= 10) {

            cout <<"    " << i+1 << "   ";
        }else{
            cout <<"    0" << i+1 << "   ";

        }

        //cout <<"    0" << i+1 << "   ";

        for(int j=0; j<noOfCourses; j++) {  //This loops on the columns


            if (A[i][j] >= 10 && A[i][j] <=99) {

                cout <<" " << A[i][j]  << "  ";
            }
            if(A[i][j] < 10) {

                cout <<"  " << A[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            if (A[i][j] == 100) {

                cout << A[i][j] << "  ";
            }
        }
        cout <<"   "<<findAverage(noOfStudents,noOfCourses);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Also How could I get the min,max of the per array?

Comment: What is the declaration of `A`?

Comment: You haven't initialized `sum` before using it, and you return during the first iteration of the outer loop. Is there a reason you aren't using `std::vector` to store the data and `std::accumulate` to add up the values? You can get min and max with `min_element` and `max_element`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `findAverage` function you have a return statement within the loop that is looping through the rows. If you want a very simple fix add another parameter to the `findAverage` function that indicates which row to calculate the average for.

```
int findAverage(int course ,int noOfGrades ){

    float sum,average;


    for (int j = 0; j<noOfStudents; j++) {

        sum += A[course][j];

    }
    average = sum / noOfGrades;
    return format(average);
 }
```

and call it like this

```
cout <<"   "<<findAverage(i,noOfCourses);
```

Comment: You still have to initialize sum to 0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I would strong recommend using containers for this task. For example you could do the following

```
typedef std::vector<float> grades;
std::vector<grades> student_grades;

//populate 

for(const grades& gr : student_grades) {
    float min, max, avg;
    std::tie(min, max)=std::minmax(gr.begin(), gr.end());
    avg=std::accumulate(gr.begin(), gr.end(), 0.0) / gr.size());
    std::cout << "Min" << min << " Max: " << max << " Avg: " << avg << std::endl;
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

Comment: Hmm, I dont have many idea about containers. I know about vectors but what does tie and accumulate do? and Do I need an extra library for them?

Comment: std::tie(min, max)=std::minmax(gr.begin(), gr.end());

What does that operation actually do?

Comment: No you don't need an extra library for them they are in the standard library, accumulate adds up all of the value in the container, and std::minmax returns a tuple (a grouping of values) of the minimum and maximum values. std::tie unpacks that tuple into existing variables. This is a very clean, efficient and modern approach to returning multiple values from a function. I'll add some references to my answer.

Comment: #include <tuple> and ensure you are compiler with -std=c++0x it is from the new standard.

Comment: if you don't have good c++11 support than you can definite do them indiviuallly like so: `float min=std::min(gr.begin(), gr.end()); float max=std::max(gr.begin(), gr.end()); float avg=std::accumulate(gr.begin(), gr.end(), 0.0f);` hope that helps

Comment: I am using Xcode 4 , It doesnt recognize tuple sadly. Ill be trying the second option now, thanks!

Comment: cool, don't forget that container are your friend you should always use contains over arrays where possible.

Comment: What error I am getting now is 'Called object type 'float' is not a function or function pointer.

avg works fine but min and max doest

Comment: make sure you have #include <algorithm> oh sorry I think that should me std::max_element and std::min_element my apologies.

Comment: I am using it already but it still doesnt let me compile unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are returning from inside your loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < noOfGrades ; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j<noOfStudents; j++) {
    ...
  }
  ...
  return ...;
}
```

Can you see how the outer loop will only ever execute once?

Comment: But when both loops executes , then It only prints me the latest one instead of the first one

Comment: That's because you reset `sum` in each loop.